# Protractor: can't get repeater element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, repeater

I'm testing basic example from https://angularjs.org/ called "Add new control".
The problem is that after adding new value to repeater I can't obtain any element . Only first one.

```
...
var listRepeater = by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos');
var list = element.all(listRepeater);
expect(list.count()).toEqual(2);

addNewElement();

expect(list.count()).toEqual(3);
expect(list.get(0).element(by.model("todo.done")).getAttribute("checked")).toEqual("true");
expect(list.get(2).element(by.model("todo.done")).getAttribute("checked")).toEqual("true");
```

After adding new element check on element's count is Ok: it's equal ti 3 and I know that new values was added properly. And I can clearly get right "checked" property of first element (it's disabled by default). But when I'm trying to get(2) element I have error about null object. Same with the get(1). Only get(0) works fine. But 2 rows repeater have by default with out a doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the second and the third elements are unchecked and don't have a `checked` attribute - this is why you are getting `null`.

Instead, a correct way to check if a checkbox is checked is to use [`isSelected()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.isSelected):

```
expect(list.get(0).element(by.model("todo.done")).isSelected()).toEqual(true);
expect(list.get(2).element(by.model("todo.done")).isSelected()).toEqual(false);
```

Worked for me.

Comment: You were right. Sad that I don't get it be myself. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a promise/synchronization/refreshing issue. See if this works, if yes, you need to start using promises.

```
it("your test", function(done){
  var listRepeater = by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos');
  var list = element.all(listRepeater);
  expect(list.count()).toEqual(2);

  addNewElement();
  browser.sleep(2000);

  setTimeout(function(){
      var listRepeater = by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos');
      var list = element.all(listRepeater);
      expect(list.get(2)
        .element(by.model("todo.done"))
        .getAttribute("checked")).toEqual("true");

      done();
  }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: No, it doesn't help. I don't think this is something about sync because by default I have 2 instances in my repeater by default and adding third one. But I can't get access to second default, only to the first one.